# Prolog: fill list with n elements

Tags: prolog

Need to make a predicate, fill(L,X,N), where L is a list formed containing N elements X. If N <= 0 or N != length of L, L should be an empty list.

Here's what I've done, I've never been able to get the if, else.. structure working correctly in Prolog:

```
fill(L,X,N) :-
   ((N =< 0) -> 
   L = [];
   length(L,I),
   ((N =\+= I) -> 
   L = [];
   fill2(L,X,N))).
fill2([H|T],X,N2) :-
   NewN = N2 - 1,
   H = X,
   fill2(T,X,NewN).
```

I also have a simpler version, that works except when N != length of L

```
fill(L,_,N) :-
   N =< 0,
   L = [].
fill([H|T],X,N) :-
   NewN = N - 1,
   H = X,
   fill(T,X,NewN).
```

So, for example, fill(L,20,4) returns L = [20,20,20,20], but fill([20,20,20],X,2) doesn't return L = [].

Comment: Are you sure about this: "if N != length(L), L should be an empty list"? If L is empty list, N is 0; if N != length(L), the predicate should probably fail.

Comment: also: `fill(L,X,N):- length(L,N), maplist( =(X), L).`.

Comment: @WillNess `fill(L,X,N):- length(L,N), maplist( =(X), L).` Is this line just making L a list of length N, and then mapping X to each index of L?

Comment: yes. it maps `=(X)` to each its element. e.g. `[A,B,C]` --> `X=A,X=B,X=C`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how Prolog is meant to be used. Predicates are not exactly functions, so they can't return. If you bind an argument to an instantiated variable:

```
?- fill([a,a,a], a, 4).
fail
```

the only sensible thing is that Prolog tells you, "this is not correct". Anyway, in this example:

```
?- fill([b,b], a, 3).
```

What should happen? Should the list be `[a,a,a]`, or should the second and third argument be `b` and `2`?

A very simple `fill`:

```
fill([], _, 0).
fill([X|Xs], X, N) :- succ(N0, N), fill(Xs, X, N0).
```

It will fail if not used properly, but you should make clear how it needs to be used.

A note: try to avoid explicit unification in the body of the predicate definition.

Comment: How would the code change if L should be an empty list if N != length(L). I can't see how to implement that without overly complicating things.

Comment: @AdamDuvall Again, with this: `fill(List, Element, N)`, if you already have a list of a certain length **and** you have an N in the predicate call, you can't change either any more. At least one of them must be a free variable.

Comment: actually you should unify *at proper time* always. sometimes it's in the head, and sometimes it's in the body, with explicit unification. :)

Comment: @WillNess Ha, got me there.... :) My rule of thumb is: do it in the body if you can't do it in the head without dumb tricks. How about that?